# angular 6 / ngx-translate and dynamic devextreme dxDatagrid columns

Tags: angular, ngx-translate, dx-data-grid

I use ngx-translate and can localise a column in dxDataGrid by binding caption in the template.html like this:

```
[caption]="'Customer.Name' | translate"
```

Now I have to requirement to create a column completely dynamic, which works in general by constructing a columns collection with the needed details.

The problem is the column header, which I only can set with a static text by calling the `columnOption` method.

I am searching for a way to define the binding of the caption using code.

Comment: I suspect you want to bind it to be able to update automatically when the language changes? You could use the TranslateService.onTranslationChange event to rebuild your table.

Comment: yes, I would like to NOT use this event... it is really expensive to update a filled grid this way

Comment: I am certainly aware of that, but how often does the language change? I'm just being pragmatic here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in ts

```
constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {}

...
const costumerName = this.translate.instant('Customer.Name');
```